# Mac Application archiving - Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error

Tags: cocoa, package, archive, mach-o, macos

I've a Mac application that uses frameworks like Obectiveflickr, PHFacebook etc.These frameworks are copied in Library/Frameworks and these are linked to the application from there.The application runs successfully but when i try to archive it (in order to package it), its giving out error like '  "Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error   ".objc_class_name_PhFacebook", referenced from:'. How can i solve this?

Thanks,

LS Developer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue got solved when i made a change to the BuildSettings of the project. 'Build Active Architecture Only' > Release is set to 'Yes'. Initially it was 'No'.

LS Developer